# Using methods defined for an object type not working when I pass the same object type

Tags: java, object, methods

Overview- 
This is a conceptual doubt.
I wanted to implement a data structure for keeping track of the MobilePhones registered.
So I created three classes-
1) Node class which has two variables -

```
class Node{
    public Object data;
    public Node next;
    public Node (Object datax) {
        this.data = datax;
    }
}
```

2) MobilePhone class

```
class MobilePhone {
    public int phoneID;

    public MobilePhone(int number) {
        this.phoneID= number;
    }

    public int number() {
        return this.phoneID;
    }}<br>
```

3) A class Myset which implements LinkedList using Node objects.
I have just shown the insert method here for the sake of simplicity.

```
// the following method inserts a MobilePhone object in front of the Myset LL
public  void Insert(Object o) {

    if(IsMember(o)) {
        // print already a list
        return;
    }

    Node temp = head;

    head = new Node(o);

    head.next = temp;
    numberPhone++;
}
```

Then in another class I use

```
MobilePhone m1MobilePhone = new MobilePhone(193);
set1Myset.Insert(m1MobilePhone);
System.out.println(set1Myset.head.data.number());
```

I defined the Node class and Myset using only Object class objects so as to generalize. 
But if I pass the object of type MobilePhone, I am not able to use the methods defined in the MobilePhone class as the compiler keeps on showing error such as that - 
"The method number() is undefined for the type Object".

My question is if I have already defined that the data type of the object that I am passing then why can't I use the methods defined for that data type?
What should I do to use them?

Comment: You would need to use generics.

Comment: Could you please elaborate upon that?

Answer (score 0):

You're referring a derived class' instance with a reference of it's base class(class Object). In that case this reference can only be used to access the methods that is defined in the class Object.

Your Insert() method's signature must allow a parameter of type MobilePhone to use the methods of it.

Comment: So in the insert method, instead of using Object, if I use MobilePhone then I can use the methods of MobilePhone?

Comment: Is there any other way to use the methods of MobilePhone while using objects because I want to use the method Insert for different data types?

Comment: Maybe checking out "generics" may help.